# On textbox char length

Tags: vb.net

I am stuck on this, if I enter 6 numbers in textbox my code runs but excludes 6th character.
Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub NumberValidationTextBox(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(datumTbox.Text.Length)
    Dim regex As New Regex("[^0-9]+")
    e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text)
    If Len(datumTbox.Text) = 5 Then
        Dim aa As String = datumTbox.Text
        Dim i As Integer = 2
        While i < aa.Length
            aa = aa.Insert(i, "/")
            i += 3
        End While
        datumTbox.Text = aa
        Dim value As String = aa
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value)
        Console.WriteLine(aa)
    Else
    End If
End Sub

 <TextBox PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" x:Name="datumTbox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="22" Margin="0,10,237,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsTabStop="False"/>
```

For string: 171291 console writes 17/12/9, somehow my last char gets excluded from string even tho that last char fires up  ' If Len(datumTbox.Text) = 5 Then'

Comment: try with `While i <= aa.Length`

Comment: Yes, it will hit the `If`, but it's length is 6 so it will be false and drop into your `Else`.  Assuming this is an onchange event handler, the output is being done when you've typed the 5th char, then not passing the If check again on the 6th.

Comment: How would I exclude that last char? @JamesThorpe

Comment: Well right now you _are_ excluding it?  Do you mean you want to include it in the output? If so, just check for when the length is 6....?

Comment: Ok, i have changed it to Length = 6 and if I type in 6 digits in textbox nothing happens. Length = 6 is only true if i type 7 digits in string. @JamesThorpe

Comment: I just noticed your event hook - you're using `PreviewTextInput` - ie it's not actually appended the character yet.  Any particular reason you chose that event?

Comment: As @JamesThorpe said, that event gets fired before the textbox.Text is actually changed.  I've never tried using that event, but the event args has a Text property which is probably the "proposed" text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to parse a date value that is entered into a TextBox where the format is ddMMyy, by iterating through the String appending the "/" after the dd and MM, and then using DateTime.Parse. This is not the right way to do this.

Instead, simply use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the input and then return the desired format from the converted Date value. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Dim time As DateTime
Dim deDE As New CultureInfo("de-DE") 'Since datumTbox.Text is German

If Date.TryParseExact(datumTbox.Text, "ddMMyy", deDE, DateTimeStyles.None, time) Then
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("dd/MM/yy"))
Else
    Console.WriteLine("The input is not in a ddMMyy format")
End If
```